# what is the correct format of a column for store UTC date time

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have a column name serverUTC.
I want to store UTC date time.I set the type is DATETIME and not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
Please suggest me how I can store UTC date time

Answer (score 0):

MySQL store date in UTC but show (select) in your time zone.
And if you insert date then convert to UTC before store.

You can use function UTC_TIMESTAMP() when selecting data or set/change 
default_time_zone.

More info and examples:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/mysql-set-utc-time-as-default-timestamp

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.htm